# Is there any way to type Immutable Map of another type?

Tags: types, flowtype, immutable.js, mapbox-gl-js

Eg. I have a type from the external library (mapboxgl.Style) and I want to create new Immutable.Map type based on that type.

So this type would cover internal properties of the original type within Immutable.Map.

Here is some code:

```
const plainStyle: mapboxgl.Style = <...>;
const style: ??? = Immutable.Map(plainStyle);

style.get('name'): String
style.get('sources'): Immutable.Map<String, Object>
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like `fromJS` would do the trick.

Something like:

```
const style = Immutable.fromJS(plainStyle)
```